# Avoiding concurrent modification in observer pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Consider you have an observer pattern implemented and that the observers can decide to unregister themselves (or other observers) from your subject on the onUpdate method.

Assuming you are using ArrayLists to save your observers this will cause a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException since you are removing items while iterating over the list.

Which is the nicest way to solve this problem?

Currently I am cloning the list so that iterate over the clone for the onUpdate method, but I believe there should be better solutions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of collections that support this. For example jME3 uses their own variant of ArrayList called `SafeArrayList`. It's an open source project so you can find the implementation there.

A better solution than cloning on every read is to copy the list on modification. Just create a new list, make the change to it, assign that back to your list of listeners.

In most cases changes to observers happens less often that looping over observers.

If you copy the list and modify the clone then anything iterating over the previous version of the list will not see the change but will also not exception.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over a copy as you're currently doing it is one solution. Using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` would be another one that is thread-safe, too. Both have a certain overhead, of course.